# Can't access keys in a json that is returned from mongoose fineOne()

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am encountering a weird issue.
I have searched and found a document in my mongoDB using mongoose by using model.findOne() like so:

```
Model.findOne({
      ID: ID
    }).then(existingDoc => {
      console.log(existingDoc );
      res.send(existingDoc );
    });
```

Now, everything works until now, it sends the json I expected to get. The looks like so:

```
{
  "_id": "5bf388cf170a974770c5c942",
  "ID": "11/2018",
  "date": "2018-11-20T04:08:47.997Z",
  "total": {
    "total_market_cap": [
      64301.06256298704
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to access these values for example:

```
 console.log(existingDoc.total);
```

I get undefined. Tried also using:

```
 console.log(existingDoc['total']);
```

And I still get undefined.

It returned undefined for everything except the _id and __v. like it is an empty object, although it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to convert it toObject

```js
Model.findOne({
      ID: ID
    }).then(existingDoc => {
      console.log(existingDoc );
      let newdoc = existingDoc.toObject();
      console.log(newdoc.myProperty)
      res.send(existingDoc );
    });
```

Comment: It worked! although I don't know why. when I used typeof on the existingDoc it was an object already. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add more explanation about this behavior? it looks interesting.

Comment: Mongoose documentation says that this method converts a document to a plain js object. After having a plan js object, we can iterate  the properties. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject